# Big-O Notation exponentials

Tags: asymptotics

I'm learning about Big-O notation for algorithm runtime, and I need some help understanding one part.

I read that for [image] the constant, *c*, does not matter as the function increases rapidly.

Does that mean that [image]?

Comment: No, $3^n$ is not in $O(2^n)$... there is no positive constant $K$ such that $3^n \le K\cdot 2^n$ for sufficiently large $n$.  Sometimes one speaks of $3^n$ being in $O^*(2^n)$; that is, $\log(3^n)$ is $O(\log 2^n)$.